# Parameter stay on Input Razor C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have a View like:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
   <input id="sStartDate" name="sStartDate" /><br>
   <input id="sFinishDate" name="sFinishDate" /><br>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" value="Generate" />

   <table>
      <!-- somedatahere... -->
   </table>
</form>
```

Then I have a Controller like:

```
public IActionResult Index(DateTime sStartDate, DateTime sFinishDate)
{
     var model = _db.Activities.Where(w => w.StartDate >= sStartDate && w.StartDate <= sFinishDate).ToList();
     return View(model);
}
```

My question:

1. How can I set the `sStartDate` and `sFinishDate` input with a default date for today?
2. When I clicked `Generate`, the input value should be stay as user selected. How can I do that?

Right now, When I click the `sStartDate` and `sFinishDate` then `Generate`. The input is set to null.

Need advice please.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Haminteu, for the first question, where did you want to set he default date? Display in the razor view? Or receive the default date when you do not enter any input?

Comment: @Rena, when View loaded in the browser... Input sStart & sFinish should be filled with today date and when user change the date then generate (post). the value should stayed as is.

Comment: The value should stay as what you change the date or still the today date?

Comment: should stay as what we change

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TempData to keep the date:

View(`ToShortDateString()` is used to display date without time, if you want to display time, just remove this method):

```
@{
    var sStartDate = TempData["sStartDate"] == null ? DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() : TempData["sStartDate"];
    var sFinishDate = TempData["sFinishDate"] == null ? DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() : TempData["sFinishDate"];
}
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
    <input id="sStartDate" name="sStartDate" value="@sStartDate" /><br>
    <input id="sFinishDate" name="sFinishDate" value="@sFinishDate"/><br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" value="Generate" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(DateTime sStartDate, DateTime sFinishDate)
{
    TempData["sStartDate"] = sStartDate.ToShortDateString();
    TempData["sFinishDate"] = sFinishDate.ToShortDateString();
    return View();
}
```